# .NET : Create custom control like UItableView in iPhone SDK

Tags: c#, iphone, .net, uitableview

i want to create a custom control (like UITableView in iPhone) in .Net using c sharp so user can scroll using mouse or keyboard navigation keys. I also want to create event when user click on any row. Currently the possible control is Datagridview which seems to me correct but i want to know the other possible approaches. So please suggest or advice other alternative

Answer (score 0):

The `DataGridView` does sound like it might fit your simple requirements, you can certainly scroll using the mouse or keyboard. Also there is the [CellMouseClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellmouseclick.aspx) which is fired when the user clicks the grid. This reports row and column index.

However, the iPhone `UITableView` is not multi-column. If you do not heen a grid-like layout (rows **and** columns), then `DataGridView` is overkill. You might want to consider [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx) instead. This has a [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event which can be used to detect row clicks.